# How to deal with node modules using ES6/ES7 language features?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dependencies, react-navigation, ecmascript-next

In a `create-react-native-app` project, I’m having trouble loading npm modules that use ES6/ES7 language features. 
 In fact, I posted a similar question but deleted it after hearing that published npm modules just **shouldn’t use** ES6/ES7 language features, so the problem was with the modules I was using.  But now I’m having trouble with a mainstream module, `React Navigation`.  In this file, for example, you’ll see the class properties that give me the error below: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/v1.5.8/src/views/TabView/TabView.js

Here's the error I get:

**Failed to compile**

```
./node_modules/react-navigation/src/views/TabView/TabView.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| class TabView extends React.PureComponent {
|   static defaultProps = {
|     lazy: true,
|     removedClippedSubviews: true,
```

What's the best way to handle `node_modules` with new language features?

Comment: Show me how you are importing the module?

Comment: Nothing special, just `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';`

Comment: You seem to be talking about experimental features, not ES7. ES7 (ES2016) was released two years ago. It did not introduce new syntax.